# Example where integration by parts formula fails for a.e. differentiable functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm studying for a qual and found this problem. We were given two absolutely continuous functions $f,g$ on $[a,b]$. The first two parts of the problem involved proving the integration by parts formula:
$$
\int_{[a,b]}fg' = f(b)g(b)-f(a)g(a) - \int_{[a,b]} f'g.
$$
This was fairly straight forward. However, the last part now asks to find an example where this formula need not hold if we only assume $f$ and $g$ are differentiable almost everywhere as opposed to absolutely continuous. Can someone provide an example/a hint for me to verify?

Comment: So far, both answers supplied show that this fails if you do not require at least that $f$ and $g$ are continuous.  You should, however, also supply a counterexample in which $f$ and $g$ are both continuous, but not both absolutely continuous.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $f(x) = g(x) = x$ on $(0,1)$, and let $f(x) = g(x) = 0$ everywhere else. Then $f$ and $g$ are a.e. differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ and $$
  \int_{[0,1]} fg' = \int_{[0,1]} x = \frac{1}{2}.
$$

But integration by parts yields $$
   \int_{[0,1]} fg' = \underbrace{f(1)g(1)}_{=0\cdot 0} - \underbrace{f(0)g(0)}_{=0\cdot 0} - \underbrace{\int_{[0,1]} f'g}_{=\int_{[0,1} x = \frac{1}{2} } = -\frac{1}{2}.
$$
The problem here is that $f(1)g(1)$ "should" be $1$, which would then yield the correct answer $1 - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$. But we forced that term to be 0 by decreeing that $f$ and $g$ be zero at one. Since this changes the functions only on a set of measure zero, it does not change any of the integrals, but it *does* change the value of $f(b)g(b) - f(a)g(a)$, since this expressions depends on the values of $f$ and $g$ at *single* points. This, as can be seen, "breaks" partial integration.

In general, whenever a formula relates the value of an integral of functions to their values at single points, it'll very likely require some property to really hold *everywhere*, not just *a.e.*. Because whenever things just hold a.e., the values at single points can be changed without changing the integrals.

Answer (score 0):

You can write something along the lines $$f(x)=x^2/2,\quad g(x)=\begin{cases}1,&x\le \frac 12\\0,&x>\frac 12 \end{cases}.$$

Then $$\int_{[0,1]}f'g=\int_0^{1/2} xdx=\frac 14.$$ After that $f(0)=g(1)=0$, hence the non-integral parts of the intergration by parts vanish.

Yet $$\int_0^1 fg'  =0$$ if you "forget" about the discontinuity of $g$ and the fact that $g$ is only piecewise differentiable.

And, for sake of completness of the answer, the derivative of $g$ is well-defined in the sense of distributions and is equal to $-\delta_{1/2}$.